# How to pass gitlab ci/cd variables to kubernetes(AKS) deployment.yaml

Tags: kubernetes, gitlab

I have a node.js (express) project checked into gitlab and this is running in Kubernetes . I know we can set env variables in Kubernetes(on Azure, aks) in deployment.yaml file.

How can i pass  gitlab ci/cd env variables to kubernetes(aks) (deployment.yaml file) ?

Answer (score 9):

You can develop your own helm charts. This will pay back in long perspective.

Other approach: there is an easy and versatile way is to put `${MY_VARIABLE}` placeholders into the deployment.yaml file. Next, during the pipeline run, at the deployment job use the `envsubst` command to substitute vars with respective values and deploy the file.

Example deployment file:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-deployment-${MY_VARIABLE}
  labels:
    app: nginx
spec:
  replicas: 3
(...)
```

Example job:

```
(...)
deploy:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - envsubst < deployment.yaml > deployment-${CI_JOB_NAME}.yaml
    - kubectl apply -f deployment-${CI_JOB_NAME}.yaml
```

Answer (score 1):

For future readers. Another way is to use a template file and generate `deployment.yaml` from the template using `envsubst`.

Template file:

```
# template/deployment.tmpl
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: deployment
metadata:
  name: strapi-deployment
  namespace: strapi
  labels:
    app: strapi

# deployment specifications
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: strapi
  serviceName: strapi

  # pod specifications
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: strapi

    # pod blueprints
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: strapi-container
          image: registry.gitlab.com/repo-name/image:${IMAGE_TAG}
          imagePullPolicy: Always
    imagePullSecrets:
    - name: gitlab-registry-secret
```

`deploy` stage in `.gitlab-ci.yml`

```
(...)
deploy:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    # deploy resources in k8s cluster
    - envsubst < strapi-deployment.tmpl > strapi-deployment.yaml
    - kubectl apply -f strapi-deployment.yaml
```

As defined here `image: registry.gitlab.com/repo-name/image:${IMAGE_TAG}`,  `IMAGE_TAG` is an environment variable defined in gitlab. `envsubst` would go through `strapi-deployment.tmpl` and substitute any variable defined there and generate `strapi-deployment.yaml` file.

Answer (score 1):

`sed` command helped me with this:

In Deployment.yaml use some placeholder, like this:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: Deployment
    metadata:
      name: myapp
    #Other configs bla-bla-bla
      spec:
          containers:
            - name: app
              image: my.registry./myapp:<VERSION>
```

And in `.gitlab-ci.yml` use sed:

```
deploy:
  stage: deploy
  image: kubectl-img
  script:
    # - kubectl bla-bla-bla whatever you want to do before the apply command
    - sed -i "s/<VERSION>/${CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA}/g" Deployment.yaml
    - kubectl apply -f Deployment.yaml
```

So the resulting `Deployment.yaml` will contain `CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA` value instead of `<VERSION>`

[Source of the solution](https://sanderknape.com/2019/02/automated-deployments-kubernetes-gitlab/)

Comment: Quick and easy, thank you very much, exactly what I needed :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to give you an easy solution that may or may not be "the solution".

To do what you want you could simply add your gitlab env variables in a secret during the cd before launching your deployment. This will allow you to use env secret inside the deployment.

If you want to do it like this you will need to think of how to delete them when you want to update them for idempotence.

Comment: This is one way to do it. But I was hoping if we can specify it in gitlab env variables  and access them, somehow. That will be the best way to do it in case we want to change them later.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be to create the thing you are deploying as a [Helm](https://helm.sh/) Chart. This would allow you to have specific variables (called values) that you can use in the templating and override at install / upgrade time.

There are many articles around getting setup with something like this.

- Here is one specifically around the context of CI/CD: https://medium.com/@gajus/the-missing-ci-cd-kubernetes-component-helm-package-manager-1fe002aac680.
- Another specifically around GitLab: https://medium.com/@yanick.witschi/automated-kubernetes-deployments-with-gitlab-helm-and-traefik-4e54bec47dcf

Comment: This is one way as well. I am not using help charts as of now.